# R: Redirecting to both stdout and a file on the fly

Tags: r, stdout, sink

Is there a way to redirect the R - output into a file and print it to stdout at the same time, on the fly?
I want to monitor the progress and document it in a file. sink() can't do both, it seems.

Found the function tee on Unix (I use Mac and Linux) but there might be an R solution.
Thanks!

Comment: See argument `split - logical: if TRUE, output will be sent to the new sink and to the current output stream, like the Unix program tee.`

Comment: Thanks Rui, exactly what I needed ( skipped reading the documentation before searching..).

Comment: It works for the output, not for the error messages, but it's good:                                Error in sink(msg, type = "message", split = TRUE) : 
  cannot split the message connection

Answer (score 1):

Function `sink` is the standard R way of redirecting output. It has an argument `split` that when set to `TRUE` will still have the output of commands print to `stdout`.
From the documentation, my emphasis.

> split
>   logical: if TRUE, output will be sent to the new sink and to the current output stream, **like the Unix program tee**.

The following example displays this behavior.
First a data set to run a command with lots of written output.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 4)
```

These instructions are meant not to mess with my workspace. Feel free to skip them.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('~/tmp')
```

Now the split `sink` example.

```
sink(file = 'sink.txt', split = TRUE)
summary(lm(y ~ x))
sink(NULL)
```

`summary` output to both stdout and the file `sink.txt`.
Clean up.

```
unlink('sink.txt')
```

And back to where I was.

```
setwd(old_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can send to a sink, say `outfile.txt` and then start `tail -f outfile.txt` in another process?

```
sink("outfile.txt")
system("tail -f outfile.txt &")
```